# Woocommerce variable product does not support image against each variation

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product

In woo commerce when we upload a product and make it a variable product.then for each variation it provides an option for image upload but when we select that option on front end it does not show that image against that variation. Does anyone know that what is the issue with it??

Comment: Probably a theme issue. Can you reproduce the issue with a default theme. Also try disabling other plugins.

Comment: i have tried on other themes as well.but still having same issue..

Comment: I assume you have set the image for each variation. And you tried disabling other plugins? Check your browser's console log. I must be a script error, because this definitely works by default. Do you have a link?

Comment: here is the link for that product.   http://lovebrite.com/product/test-product/